# Change class name every time page refresh

Tags: javascript, class, refresh

I was on a website recently and I have saw that every time the website refresh the class name change. I was searching for this on google but I couldn’t find anything. Is there any way where I can change the class name every time the website refresh in JavaScript?

Comment: What makes you think the classname changes in javascript instead of server side?

Comment: You could pick a different class at random for each refresh?  Or derive a class name from the current time?  Or leverage browser storage if necessary to track the last class name?  Some more context might be helpful if you could provide it-- what _specifically_ do you want to do?

Comment: Also, the answer to your question heavily relies on other things, like -- why is there a classname on this dom element to begin with? Is the classname connected to css styles? Do you expect the css styles to "come with" when you change the classname on the dom element?

Comment: What I want accomplish is that when the website refresh i want it to change the class name so the background image can change in CSS

Comment: so have a list of classes and randomly pick one from the list on page load.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: Can you write the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the class name here's what you can do.

```
  let element = document.getElementById("elementId") 
function getRandomNumber(){ 
var randomNumOfLet = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(62))
return randomNumOfLet
}
function makeClass(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
} 


element.class = makeClass(getRandomNumber())
```